# Image not displayed on page - (Express, Pugjs)

Tags: javascript, express, pug, pugjs

I am trying to display an image on my page using pug template, but the image is not displayed on the page.

I have the following setup/ files:

**index.js**

```
app.use('/images', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist/assets')))
```

**template.pug**

```
img.logo(src='/images/logo.png')
```

The logo.png is located in the /dist/assets/ folder.

I don't get any errors but the image is not loaded/ displayed and when I open the image link from the developers tool in a new tab, the image is shown. Not sure if I am missing anything. Can anyone please explain why this is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `logo` property to set the image path which is wrong.

It shoud be:

```
img.image(src='/images/logo.png')
```